# Node JS + MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, nodejs, sql, socket.io

Tomé como esqueleto el código generado por Express JS y todo funciona bien. La cuestión es que al momento de mostrar mi pagina .../uno, esta me muestra el resultado adecuado pero solamente por unos 5 ms y el contenido desaparece. Saben por qué sucede esto?, agradecería que puedan darme una mano al respecto. Adjunto el código en la ruta UNO.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

var socket = require('../source/socket');
var conn = require('../source/conn');

var valor = [];

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  connection = conn.open();

  connection.query("SELECT nomParam, valParam FROM tParametro WHERE idVista = '1';", function (error, results, fields) {
    global.valSocket = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      valor.push(results[i].nomParam + "|" + results[i].valParam);

      global.nomSocket = "valor";
      global.valSocket = valor;
    }

    socket.emit();
    res.render('uno');
  });

  valor = [];
  connection.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

y también el código en el archivo JavaScript del cliente:

```
 window.onload = function () {

    var valor = [];
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
    var content = document.getElementById("content");

    socket.on('valor', function (data) {
        valor = data;

        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
            html += '<b>' + (valor[i]) + ': </b><br>';
        }
        content.innerHTML = html;
    });
}
```

Para dejarlo mas claro, les muestro también el código de mi pagina UNO.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>UNO</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src='/javascripts/unoScript.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <body>
        <div id='content'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: alguien???? porfa

Comment: Me podrías mostrar el error que te da la consola? presiento que como estás utilizando Socket io al intentar actualizar "explota" por hacer doble conección a MYSQL

Comment: gracias por responder. no me sale ningún mensaje de error en la consola. el único problema es que al mostrar mi pagina, el contenido desaparece inmediatamente luego de mostrarse